# clicking twice on the same element and then on another element brings the first elment to the "clicked" state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an interactive illustration where you can hover over elements and then if you click on them you can see a popover and the clicked element gets black. It works quite good, but there is a problem with the click and hover code. If one clicks on the same element twice in a row and then on another element, the first element gets black. Try for yourself: http://labs.tageswoche.ch/grafik_osze

Here is the code:

```
var sourceSwap = function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
        var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');

        $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
        $this.attr('src', newSource);
    }
};

var makeActive = function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    // bring the active back (if any) to the first state
    if ($('img.active').length) {
        var newSource = $('img.active').data('alt-src');

        $('img.active').data('alt-src', $('img.active').attr('src'));
        $('img.active').attr('src', newSource);
        $('img.active').removeClass('active');
    }
    $this.toggleClass('active');
}

$(function() {
    $('img[data-alt-src]')
        .each(function() { 
            new Image().src = $(this).data('alt-src'); 
        })
        .hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);

    $('img[data-alt-src]').on('click', makeActive);
});
```

To try for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/8wtvvka5/

Comment: The problematic code lies with `.toggleClass()`. When you double click on the element, you are executing toggleClass twice. Since it is a binary function then clicking once or twice will produce different results.

Comment: @Terry I changed it to .addClass(), but it doesnt change anything. What would you suggest?

Comment: Would be easier to help if you can create a minimal test case, as a code snippet or a fiddle.

Comment: @Terry I added a jsfiddle to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried this on fiddle:

```
function swap(e)
{
    var src = e.attr('src');
    var active = e.hasClass('active');

    var dark =  src.indexOf('_h.png', src.length - '_h.png'.length) !== -1;
    e.attr('data-src-dark', dark); 

    if (active || e.attr('data-src-dark') == true) return;

    e.attr('src', e.attr('data-alt-src'));
    e.attr('data-alt-src', src); 

    return active;
}

var sourceSwap = function () 
{
      if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) 
      {
           swap($(this)); 
      }
};

var makeActive = function() 
{
     var active = $(this).hasClass('active');

     $('img.active').each(function()
     {                          
         $(this).removeClass('active'); swap($(this)); 
     });

     if (active) $(this).removeClass('active'); 
     else $(this).addClass('active');

     swap($(this)); 
 }

  $(function() {
      $('img[data-alt-src]')
          .each(function() { 
              new Image().src = $(this).data('alt-src'); 
          })
          .hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);

      $('img[data-alt-src]').on('click', makeActive);
  });
```

$('img.active') is a complete set of elements so you should use the 'each' function to handle them all

JUST COPY-AND-PASTE to fiddle to check it out yorself :)

Comment: doesnt work for me, could you share the whole fiddle?

Comment: i am not sure if i explained the problem well enough. First one clicks on the army picture (gets black), then clicks again on the army picture (gets white), and then clicks on the van (gets black). If you do that, the army picture becomes black as well. And that's the problem.